# MSI Installer error-dialog localization (WiX)

Tags: wix

I have created an MSI installer for a .NET 3.5 application written in Visual Studio Express 2008. The installer UI is localized (to danish) and looks fine. My problem is that errors, say a previous version is installed and needs to be removed first, the error dialog is in english. How do I localize error-dialogs too?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Visual Studio, but have you checked out http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson2.php#2.3 - you need to ensure you specify the correct language and codepages in the **Product** and **Package** tags. You might need to edit the source wxs file if VS doesn't provide a GUI for this.